# discarding all changes in a fork and getting it synced with the original?

Tags: git, github

I have made some changes to my fork in github. I changed the master of my fork by mistake, made few commits and then realized I have to create a branch and code on that bug branch, which I did later. Then, I tried to squash commits and remove commits from git log from the master in the process, I think I messed everything up. I want to undo all the changes to my fork, get it in sync with original and restart my work. How do I do that without deleting my fork and forking it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the commits in your `master` branch,  you just have to checkout it and reset to the older commit you want:

```
Git checkout master
git reset --hard <ShaOfTheDesiredCommit>
```

But I'm pretty sure that you could save your work and don't have to make it again! 
Look at the reflog `git reflog` and find the reference of the commit before you mess it up with the rebase/squash. 
Then you just have to create a new branch on this commit to retrieve your good work by doing :

```
git checkout -b my_branch <ShaOfTheFoundCommit>
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I find out SHA of the desired commit considering my desired commit is the latest bug fix by the user who is other than me?

Comment: Dig in your history using `git log` for exemple, you could add an alias for `git log --pretty=format:'%Cred%h %Cgreen%<(10,trunc)%cd %C(auto)%d%Creset%s %C(bold blue)%an' --abbrev-commit--graph`

Comment: Your answer saved my day! I checked out a new branch with an SHA when I first cloned the repo. Then I made changes and pushed. Thanks :)